# Calling a parameterless constructor from a parametrized constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, constructor

I know that we can call a parametered constructor from other constructor using constructor chaining.

But,

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");

            var t1 = new T1("t2");


        }
    }

    public class T1
    {
        public T1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("t1");
        }

        public T1(string s):base()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```

this doesn't seem to call the base constructor (without any parameters).

Any ideas ?

EDIT:

Current: t2 is printed. t1 is not on the console.

so, I have resorted to the following method:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");

        var t1 = new T1("t2");


    }
}

public class T1
{
    private void privateMethod()
    {
          Console.WriteLine("common method");
    }

    public T1()
    {
        privateMethod();
    }

    public T1(string s):base()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        privateMethod();

    }
}
```

Is there any better ways of doing this ?

Comment: Where's the base class in this ?

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - they meant to use `this` and were incorrectly thinking `base` referred to the T1 constructor. In this case, `base` is actually `System.Object`

Comment: OP, quick debugging tip - In Visual Studio, click on `base()` and press F12. You'll see what it refers to. Now swap it for `this()` and then press F12 and you'll see that it now refers to the `T1` constructor. If you're not getting the programming flow you're expecting, step through line by line and it'll help identify the source of the issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for `this()`:

```
public class T1
{
    public T1()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("t1");
    }

    public T1(string s) : this()
    {
       Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the keyword `this`, `base` will call the parent class (as in the class you're extending).

Answer (score 1):

You're actually calling `Object()` constructor when you use the `base` keyword. You want to use the `this` keyword

```
public class T1
{
    public T1()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("t1");
    }

    public T1(string s) : this()
    {
       Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: great explanation for the line 1`you are calling the Object() constructor when you use the **base** keyword`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, for calling the parameterless constructor you have to use `:this()`  (`base()` calls the parameterless constructor of the base class)

However, I think this is a bad practice. The constructor **with** parameters is the one that defines better the initialization of the class, and thus, the parameterless constructor should call it rather than vice versa.

i.e:

```
public class T1
{
    public T1():this(String.Empty) // <= calling constructor with parameter
    {
       Console.WriteLine("t1");
    }

    public T1(string s)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

rather than:

```
public class T1
{
    public T1()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("t1");
    }

    public T1(string s) : this()  // <= calling parameterless constructor 
    {
       Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

BTW, it seems that the language is going towards encouraging using a primary constructor using, well - [Primary constructors](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/08/14/c-6-0-features-part-ii-primary-constructors.aspx) (it is was an experimental feature in C# 6 that was removed, not sure if for good...)

Answer (score 0):

`this` called the current class instance while `base` the parent.